# Overheating of LM1117 SOT223, 5v-3.3v

Tags: voltage-regulator, electrical, overheat

I'm having problems with my design. I put the schematic here, maybe someone can find an error that I didn't find yet.

EDITED[I forgot the schematic, sorry...]

[image]

The microcontroller, dsPIC, has the fololwing current characteristics:
Typical ......................................................... 41 mA
Maximum ..................................................... 60 mA
Maximum current into VDD pin ...................... 300 mA

The FT232R' operating Supply Current is:
Icc1 Normal Operation ................................... 15 mA

Considering the Led current as:
I_led ...........................................................  10 mA

The total current would be at worse case, something aroud 325 mA, maybe a bit higher.

Below, the are 2 photos of my self-made PCB. The smd chip is the LM1117 SOT223. I put saliva on the Tab output pin and it instantaneously evaporated, I could hear and feel it, it was very hot. So, I think it was at much more than a 100°C.
What could explain it, why it became so hot , and what can I do to fix it in another version ?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

With my best regards.

(click for larger images)

Comment: I'm not seeing your schematic anywhere.

Comment: Lol at licking the board to see if it's hot

Comment: @BeB00 Sniffing the board is great way to check baud rate too :)

Comment: Please share the schematics.. Pictures of board files will be helpful but later

Comment: @brhans Thank you, I edited the post and already added the schematics. Sorry, I really forgot it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regulator appears to be connected incorrectly.

[image]

The minus side of the two tantalum caps (presumably your ground) is connected to the "input" pin.

Putting reverse voltage on the chip is a good way to turn it permanently into a heater or NED (Noise Emitting Diode).

---

Your problem may be visible in the schematic, but it's probably more likely that you have a problem with the mapping of the schematic symbol pins to the footprint.

Comment: I agree he laid out the pads from top view but located on bottom side, so it is upside down. And he is using 2x as much solder as needed

Comment: Yes, Spehro Pefhany was right, I inverrted the regulator and now it does not overheat anymore. But, is possible that the short period that the regulator became reversed could damage something ? For example, the output of LM1117 is about 1.64V and the FT232R appears to start overheating very slowly...

Comment: If your input voltage was only 5V it seems unlikely the FT232R would be damaged (if it was connected correctly).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking at "10.1.1 Heatsink Requirements" in the datasheet. There is no heat dissipating copper on your PCB whatsoever. Also, check you power supply. Is it indeed 5V?

Comment: Second the power supply check.  Your tantalum input cap looks burnt, although that could be from soldering - hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

EE's must use their mechanical and thermodynamic skills here.

\$R_{θJA}\$ = Junction-to-ambient thermal resistance 61.6  °C/W  Assumes 1 sq in copper
but with almost none it's **~ 136 °C/W**
\$R_{θJC}~\$= (top) Junction-to-case thermal resistance 42.5 °C/W

We can estimate the case to ambient Resistance (136-42.5)=94°C/W rise in temp or roughly 1 Watt for 120 °C   with a voltage drop of *correction)* 5-3.3=1.7V  or 590 mA/W  out of 800 mA max or 125'C max

Next time read about thermal cooling requirements . **I suggest 1~2 sq in of copper per Watt.**

This is SOT-223 package with a thermal tab.
[image]

Comment: But 5V - 3.3V is only 1.7V, which equals about 0.55W if his board really draws 325mA. So with your calculated 94°C/W, case temperature should only be about 52°C over ambient temperature. I don't think the microcontroller is even drawing 300mA, so that could imply there is a problem with his PCB that the regulator is becoming so hot.

Comment: Yes Marco I agree

Answer (score 2):

The voltage across the regulator is 5-3.3 or 1.7 volts.  At 325 ma the power is 1.7*0.325 or 0.55W.  The data sheet gives a temperature rise of 186°C per watt, so if you run 0.55 W the rise is 102°C.  If room temperature is 25°C, this puts you about 127°C, so your part is probably working as it should.

[image]

That power (and heat) will always be there no matter which linear regulator you use, so the only way to decrease the local temperature is to add a heat sink.  You could also use a switcher to increase the regulator efficiency.

Comment: 127 °C ought to begin thermal shutdown

Comment: It will be close if there is really 325 ma.

Comment: The termal resistance is 186°C/W, but for the TO package! For the SOT-223 package that the OP is using WITHOUT copper area it's about 130°C/W. With only about half a square inch of copper it would be less than 70°C/W.